QUORUM reads fail when one of two DCs are down
We have 2 DCs with RF=3 in this cluster: DC1 3 nodes DC2 3 nodes
The customer has requested that when DC2 goes down (all 3 nodes down), they want to keep the cluster working without any quorum issues.
From the customer: When the DC2 region goes down (all 3 nodes down), and they tried to execute something from the studio or fabric servers, they get the following error
Exception in wsSearchContact() java.sql.SQLTransientException:\
  com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: \
  Not enough replicas available for query at consistency QUORUM \
  (4 required but only 3 alive)

In our case, when we tried to keep one node up from DC2 and 3 nodes from DC1, the cluster worked without any quorum issues.
We are looking for the right configuration for this cluster for both Cassandra and Fabric sides.
I tried to set consistency level to Local_Quorum

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

So there are essentially 6 replicas across 2 DCs. Running queries at QUORUM consistency therefore requires 4 replicas to be up.
I see two solutions here:
Build two connection objects. One of the connection objects uses a LocalDatacenter of "DC1", and the other uses a LocalDatacenter of "DC2." Run queries at a consistency level of LOCAL_QUORUM, which will only require 2 replicas. How to programmatically choose between the two connection objects at runtime is entirely up to you, but basically if one fails you should have it default to the other. This solution also eliminates cross-DC traffic, as each connection is "sticky" to a DC.
The simpler solution, would be to use a consistency level of TWO. That won't prevent cross-DC traffic, but it will perform much better than what you have now (which guarantees cross-DC traffic in every query). Plus, you'll still get a "loose quorum" of a single DC.
TBH - I'm not sure how Fabric works, but ideally, you would have multiple instances of the application (or service layer) strongly-tied to the same, physical DC that the Cassandra nodes are running in, and querying at LOCAL_QUORUM (or some other "local" consistency level). That way when DC1 fails, it takes the DC1 application stack with it. Load balancing is then done at the (web) application level, and would only send requests to app servers that are actually running.

The UnavailableException returned by the driver is expected behaviour because there are not enough replicas available to satisfy the required consistency level.
QUORUM requires at least 51% of replicas to be available. With 6 total replicas (3 x 2 DCs), 4 replicas are required to achieve QUORUM but if one DC is down, 3 of the 6 replicas will be unavailable so you cannot query the database.
LOCAL_QUORUM on the other hand only requires at least 51% of replicas in the local DC. Since a DC has 3 replicas (RF=3) then only 2 of the 3 replicas are required to satisfy LOCAL_QUORUM. Cheers!
